# How to handle two type input box?

Tags: html, input

How to create a input box that with 2 parts that 1st part not editable with default text and rest of that editable by user.

`<input type='text' value='read only'><input type='text' value='editable>`

Mix 2 input in 1 input.

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try mix two inputs to look like one as @DoeNietZoMoeilijk proposed.

You can achieve it by HTML and CSS, try this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="Read only" id="first" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="text" value="Editable" id="second" />
```

CSS:

```
#first {
    border-right: none;
}

#second {
    border-left: none;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

[Here is example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gC42/)

And here is example snippet:

```css
#first {
    border-right: none;
}

#second {
    border-left: none;
    margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="This is read only part" id="first" readonly="readonly" />
<input type="text" value="Editable" id="second" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't really mix two inputs in one input, of course, but using CSS you should be able to make two inputs *look* like one. Setting the [readonly attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-readonly) on the first input renders it... well, read-only.